# How to remove Facebook page likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

I manage a Facebook page that had 150k likes. It was hacked. Then sold. Then Facebook gave the page back but it had doubled the amount of likes to 300k.

Half my likes are fake, which makes the page pointless and worse, every post I make it's flooded with likes and content in Arabic I would suppose from bot machines.

All instructions to remove likes point to:

```
Settings -> People and Other Pages
```

But on my page it had only a handfull of those and, after deletion, it currently shows "No results found" even though the page has currently 298k likes.

**Anyone knows a way to remove those fake likes?**

Comment: I don't think you can prevent someone from "liking" a page, whether it's a real or fake like, because Facebook can't judge it... unless you can prove that those accounts exist for a particular agenda.

Comment: @AndrewT. you can prevent and you can remove the like. As stated on the question in "settings -> people and other pages" you can both ban the person from the page thus preventing another like and or interaction or you can simply remove the like which would allow the person to like again.

The issue here is that the page has 300k likes and thus some trigger came up and people who like the page only appear on that menu for a very short period of time.

Answer (score 3):

If all your likers are not showing up on

```
Settings -> People and Other Pages
```

an alternate way to handle the flood of content that you don't want might be to use their posts to remove them.

Each reply you get has an 'X' on the RHS. If you click on that it will Hide the comment. Then it will display several options where the reply used to be displayed:-

```
Unhide   Delete   Report   Ban <name>
```

You can then click to Ban that person.

This will only work for comments, not likes, but it will clean up any of the active users on your page that you don't want. Those that only like and don't comment are perhaps less of a worry anyway.

Comment: Thanks. My issue here has more to do with the "like amount" as a form of prestige than actually the trouble users might cause. My page is country specific and during the hack page was sold to another country so it would be straightforward to hide the page from that second non-related country. Nonetheless thank you for the answer.